# Issues with jQuery Datatables filters outside table wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have this table http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/index.php?theme=metronic_admin&page=index.html

It's using datatable to load data via ajax. I what to move the filters outside table wrapper but when I do this the filter function isn't working any more. Does anyone has an example on how to bind an external filter form and attach it to a datatable?

I found something here http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/external.html but it's purely documented and I can't manage to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use [fnServerParams](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnServerParams) for this.

This is in the datatable initialisation code:

```
var oTable = $('#table').dataTable({
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        aoData.push({ "name": "myParam", "value": $('#mySelector').val() });
      }
```

Your external form calls the table's fnFilter method:

```
$('#mySelector').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    oTable.fnFilter(this.value)
});
```

I use a server-side data source, so would get the passed parameter using Request.QueryString["myParam"], your method of table population might be different.